# Saber si una pagina web esta en linea Java Script

Tags: javascript

necesito saber si existe algun metodo para saber si una pagina web esta disponible con algun metodo javascript hasta el momento he escontrado esto pero no funciona

```
 
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', cadena, false);
 
if (request.status == "200") {
 document.write(cadena + "  OK");
}
 
if (request.status === "404") {
    document.write (" Error conexión");
 
}´´´
```

Comment: A disponible te refieres a que existe y te retorne un 200, no?

Comment: Puedes usar el método HEAD. Tal vez te sirva [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/429423/ocultar-tab-de-modal-si-no-existe-contenido-en-directorio/429647#429647), solo cambia `GET` por `HEAD`.

Comment: si lo que me refiero es tomar la direccion www.google.com y que me diga si esta en linea o no

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres saber que la página este disponible y retorne un 200 puedes hacer una solicitud http, la forma más actualizada de hacerlo es con `fetch`

```
fetch('laurl.com')
.then(response => {
   if(response.status ==200){
        document.write(cadena + "  OK")
    }else{
        trhow 'error'
    }
})
.catch(err =>document.write (" Error conexión");)
```

Aquí te dejo la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)