# ¿Habrá alguna manera de ver si una URL existe para poder acceder? con JS o PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Código para generar URLs, JS

```
new URL("/", urlPagina).href;
```

Comment: Supongamos que tenemos N URL posibles.

Comment: La pregunta es medio confusa.. para poder ver si una url existe haces un request a la misma y te fijas si devuelve algo.. vos que queres intentar?

Comment: @gbianchi tengo N cantidad de URLs pero no todas son accesibles o se pueden acceder ósea no existen, para no estar probando de una por una quiero saber si existe alguna función que haga el trabajo más rápido y validar cual si y cual no.

Comment: Sí, puedes ejecutar una petición con el método HEAD. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/429647/54039), está con _jQuery_, pero no es tan difícil cambiarla a Javascript puro.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Ocultar tab de modal si no existe contenido en directorio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/429423/ocultar-tab-de-modal-si-no-existe-contenido-en-directorio)